# What variable needs to be identified?

Tags: java, variables

I am a beginner in java. There is an error which appears 15 times in lines 24, 27, 29, 30, 35, 36, 37, 42, 43 and 46, saying:

```
 //Tokens cannot be resolved to a variable
```

And:

```
// i cannot be resolved to a variable
```

What variables do these errors want to identify? Because I thought I identified everything and I don't understand what variables my code still needs.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Jo_code {

    public static int wordFrequency(String s) {
        String tokens[] = s.split(" ");// splits the words
        int count = tokens.length;
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Write your sentence or type END to quit the program:");// prints out the first instruction.
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //object initialisation.
        String line = " ";//declaration for letters(String) characters.
        int max = 20; //declaration for number(int) characters.
        while ((line = scan.nextLine()) != null) { //scanner instruction, get a line from the key board.
            if (line.equals("END")) {
                break;// if you are happy with the code, then type "END", and the code will stop running.
            } else { // if you decide not to type "END" the program will continue to allow you to type sentences.  
                String[] array = line.split(" ");// splits the words
                System.out.println("your sentence is " + line);//prints out what you have typed.
                System.out.println("The total of words for the line is " + tokens.length);// prints out the total of words that you have typed.
                int maxTokensLength = 0;
                int tokensLength = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {// this line of code checks for what must be true to carry on.
                    array[i] = array[i].replaceAll("a-zA-Z]", "");
                }
                tokensLength = array[i].length();
                tokensLength = tokens[i].length();
                if (tokensLength > maxTokensLength) {
                    maxTokensLength = tokensLength;
                }
            }
        }
        int[] intArray = new int[maxTokensLength + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) { // this line of code checks for what must be true to carry on.
            intArray[array[i].length()]++;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < intArray.length; i++) { // this line of code checks for what must be true to carry on.
            System.out.printf("%word(s) of length %d<br>", intArray[i], i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) { // this line of code checks for what must be true to carry on.
            System.out.println("word " + i + ": " + tokens[i] + " = " + tokens[i].length() + " characters");
        }

        System.out.println("The length for the word " + tokens[i] + " is = " + tokens[i].length());//This line of code prints out the word frequency for each word. 
        System.out.println("The word frequency of the whole sentence is =");//results 
        System.out.println("type END to quit");//instructions
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for any help, its much appreciated!

Comment: `System.out.println("The length for the word " + tokens[i] + " ...` out of scope for i. similar for tokens

Comment: tokens is a local variable defined in wordFrequency. no other method can see it.

Comment: First thing to do: learn how to format your code. It'll make it *much* easier for you to understand, and for others to help you.

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, your very first for loop has no open and close brackets. This means only the first statement is considered part of the for loop. so the statement 'tokensLength = array[i].length();' can't reach the variable i because it is not in the for loop. I believe adding open and close brackets around everything you want in the first for loop should fix it